# Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined

Tags: webpack

I am getting the following error. Everything has been working great in my app for months, but this just started happening after running `npm install`.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_require__ is not defined
    at eval (client.js:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:33:11
    at Object../web/client.js (bundle.js:9667)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:768)
    at fn (bundle.js:131)
    at Object.0 (bundle.js:9678)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:768)
    at bundle.js:904
    at bundle.js:907
```

Comment: Any ideas on what to look for to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Could occur because of  `mode: "development"` in `webpack.config.js`. A possible solution is to also add `devtool: "inline-source-map"`, else, set `mode: "production"`

Comment: It could be because of a number of reasons. If you don't mind sharing your code (through GitHub or similar). Maybe I could help you check

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message with my Vue devserver, and the culprit was a Firefox extension called Anti-Adblock Blocker.

Doesn't sound like that is your issue, but for anyone having the same problem the root cause might be your browser extensions.